# Why does EclipseLink's PerformanceMonitor show Cachehits even when shared and query caches are disabled?

Tags: performance, jpa, caching, eclipselink, performancecounter

I am using EclispeLink with the object cache and query caches disabled in persistence.xml:

```
<property name="eclipselink.query-results-cache" value="false"/>
<property name="eclipselink.cache.shared.default" value="false"/>
```

None of the entities have `@Cacheable` or `@Cache` annotations, and none of the named queries have hints to enable cache.

Why do I still see a non-zero count when I enable profiling using `PerformanceMonitor`?
I also see some entries which show non-zero cache hit count.

```
Operation   Value (ns)
Counter:CacheHits   24
....
Counter:ReadObjectQuery:mine.data.impl.DataImpl:item    8
Counter:ReadObjectQuery:mine.data.impl.DataImpl:item:CacheHits  8
....
```

Comment: There is still a cache at the EntityManager level, allowing it to resolve circular references in object graphs, and ensure that find returns the same entity instance if called repeatedly - does that line up with your cache hits number?

Comment: Thanks for your response Chris! Then this cache is not the L2 cache, is that a correct understanding? I am not sure if I understood you question "does that line up with your cache hits number?" But looking at the profiler, I am not able to distinguish "this" cache from the L2 cache hits or query cache hits - it just gives me one single count for cache hits.

Comment: Each time a ReadQuery uses any cache instead of having to go to the DB, I believe it counts as a cache hit for the PerformanceMonitor, but I'm guessing based on usage from long ago and your own statement that you turned caching off. You'd have to debug/log to verify if this seems accurate; it has far too many stats for me to remember how they are all gathered without looking at the implementation class and using a debugger. You can turn on SQL logging and see if queries are executed for each 'readObjectQuery' EclipseLink uses to build your object model (and references within the object model)